# How to permanently make the Output of python codes to appear in a different color in the terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, .bash-profile

I found it really annoying when I use terminal that everything is in one color. I am looking for a way to print the output of my python code in a different color on the terminal console, so it will easier for me to distinguish the output of my code from the standard lines on terminal console  (standard lines i.e. `cd thisfile`).

I am not looking for a way to specifically print colored python output to terminal like the following link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python

I am looking for a solution that everytime I open up terminal and run python scripts, the output will appear in a slightly different color. I want the effect to be permanent. Similar to turning on `syntax on`, once I turn it on, it is in the setting and I don't have to turn it on everytime  I launch terminal.

And preferably, if possible, some code that I can just add directly to my `.bash_profile` that can help me achieve that, since I am not too familiar with bash scripting.

Comment: How about `alias python='tput setaf 1;  python; tput sgr0'` <-- this will make all your Python red

Comment: I added  your code to the `bash_profile`. Now everytime I perform `python script.py` in terminal, it only brings me to the python interactive shell. Then I do execfile('script.py'). The output still come out as green (the original color I have in terminal).

Comment: Also see https://github.com/sickill/stderred